# Fetch API return undefined for XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, api, react-native

I have an API that returns XML. I'm developing a react native application and I'm using fetch api to fetch data from server.

The problem is, my data is dynamic and some times theres a linebreak in xml data which cause the fetch api return `undefined`

```
fetch('http://myUrl')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(xml => { ... // return my data })
```

Here the `res.text()` returns undefined when there's a linebreak in my XML. But when all my XML is in one line there's no problem.

I can't change or fix this issue on the server side because this data in provided by our clients with a CMS.

I receive my data but I can't access the value when the XML has a linebreak. I also tried `res.blob` and `FileReader`. I need HELP